# Как создать функцию меняющую склонение месяца? Не работает CASE() после того как засунул его в функцию

Tags: sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо вносить в договор дату в формате: "26 февраля 2024 г."
Эта дата хранится в БД, ее нужно просто подгрузить и нормально отформатировать.
Для этого я обращался к месяцу с помощью:  `LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate))`, однако в таком случае получается месяц в именительном падеже - "февраль".

Чтобы избежать подобной проблемы, я создал функцию:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[РодПадежМес] (@Tdate varchar(12))
returns varchar(12) 
AS
BEGIN
        declare @MorphedMonth varchar(12)
        set @MorphedMonth = (case 
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'январь' then 'января'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'февраль' then 'февраля'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'март' then 'марта'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'апрель' then 'апреля'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'май' then 'мая'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'июнь' then 'июня'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'июль' then 'июля'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'август' then 'августа'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'сентябрь' then 'сентября'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'октябрь' then 'октября'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'ноябрь' then 'ноября'
        when LOWER(DATENAME(month, @Tdate)) = 'декабрь' then 'декабря'
        else 'ошибка'
        end)
  return @MorphedMonth
END
```

Однако при использовании этой функции в запросе выдает ошибку

```
declare @Tdate datetime
Set @Tdate=GETDATE()
Select dbo.РодПадежМес(Lower(DATENAME(month, @Tdate))) as 'MorphedMonth'
FROM Таблица
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция заработала?

Comment: а нельзя было `case month(@tdate) when 1 then 'января' ...` сделать, или вы не ищите легких путей?

Comment: У вас неявное преобразование даты, поэтому возникает баг. Используйте явное преобразование функцией `convert` или другие функции поведение которых однозначное. При неявном преобразовании в разных ситуациях дата чуть по разному конвертируется.

Comment: Нашел почему выдавало ошибку. При вызове функции нужно передавать просто дату: `Select dbo.РодПадежМес(@Tdate) as 'MorphedMonth'`. Уже нашел способ лучше, благодаря ответам, но решил добавить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Форматирование даты с правильными склонениями месяца работает из коробки без велосипедов:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd MMMM yyyy', 'ru-RU')

---------------
01 февраля 2024
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваш ответ спас меня от лишних мучений